# How to convert HQL with Group By to QueryOver?

Tags: nhibernate, hql, queryover

I have a HQL query:

```
select max(l.Num) from SomeTable l group by l.Type, l.Iteration
```

How can I translate/convert it to QueryOver?

Following one:

```
var grouped = session.QueryOver<SomeTable>()
    .SelectList(l => l
      .SelectGroup(x => x.Type)
      .SelectGroup(x => x.Iteration)
      .SelectMax(x => x.Num));
```

will generate SQL:

```
SELECT
    MAX(l.Num),
    l.Type,
    l.Iteration
FROM
    SomeTable l
GROUP BY
    l.Type,
    l.Iteration
```

which is not what I expect – I don’t want to have Type and Iteration in Select.

I'm using that query as subquery for `select z from c where z IN (subquery)`.

Comment: AFAIK still not possible with queryover/criteria, see https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1426

Answer (score 0):

try with this statement, I've used Aliases and UnderlyingCriteria

```
SomeTable someTb = null;

var grouped = session.QueryOver<SomeTable>(() => someTb)
                .SelectList(l => l.SelectMax(() => someTb.lnum))
                .UnderlyingCriteria.SetProjection(
                                   Projections.Group(() => someTb.Type)
                                   ,Projections.Group(() => someTb.Iteration))
                .List();
```

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: @Feber - thanks, but this will not work. UnderlyingCriteria just enables to use criteria query in QueryOver. Additionally, query provided by you do: `select type, iteration from SomeTable group by type, iteration` - is not event selecting max value.